# Photoshop CC (Creative Cloud) Blurry Images When Reducing Size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, adobe-creative-cloud

I just started using Photoshop CC – previously I was using CS2, which was great but is no longer available for free download.

For some reason, when I throw an image into Creative Cloud (current version), it automatically resizes to fit in the image workspace. When it is not wide enough to fit the dimensions, I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the transform bar to maintain dimensions, but it blurs the image.

Never a problem downsizing in CS2 – What gives?

I feel it is shrinking the image to fit in the image that I'm working with, then I go to expand it and lose quality.

In CS2, I would throw a high quality image in the workspace (2500px × 1400px say), create a copy of that image, then drag onto the image space I'm working on (25% - 625px × 350px) then shrink to fit
by holding <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. 
The image would come out looking crisp because I'm downsizing.

I guess my question is how do I replicate the CS2 results or process in Photoshop CC and maintain quality?

I'm about to go back to CS2!

Comment: Downsizing images without choosing an appropriate [resampling method](https://www.photoshopessentials.com/essentials/resizing-images-email-web-photoshop-cc/) may cause loss of quality as for enlargments. Before resizing you should also convert the layer to [smart object](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the following option is unchecked in preferences[image]